# is it possible to create warp technology(or some form of quick space travel)?

Tags: science-based

i would like space travel to be as realistic as possible for my sci-fi story, but I've heard that warp speed can destroy people and ships, and wormholes are too unstable for travel and very risky since there is no way of knowing where you are going.

Comment: Realistic as in hard SF? No, it's impossible.

Comment: You have one thing reversed. A wormhole mouth can (theoretically) be placed with a very high degree of precision. In SF this is often done via a relativistic spaceship known as a "line layer" (think of a truck or ship reeling out a very long cable with one wormhole mouth at the end of the cable and the other on board the truck). Alcubierre drives create a "bubble" inside the warped space which is cut off from the outside universe, so anyone inside will not be able to see out (nor anyone outside see in).

Answer (score 3):

**To date, not one warp speed traveler has been destroyed because they didn't know where they were going.**  Of course, that's mostly because modern science has never sent *anything* faster than light.  Anything at all.  Ever.  In fact, its currently believed it cannot be done.

Now there are all sorts of loopholes which have been proposed and explored, such as the Alcubierre drive.  Some of them don't even violate the laws of physics, but given that we wont see warp technology until we figure out warp science, you've got a lot of wiggle room on the "realistic" bit.

If you really want to explore space travel using things which are currently considered "possible," you limit yourself to travel within the solar system, and travel via generation ships, which is a topic with many questions on this stack exchange.

Comment: This started as a comment explaining why the question should be closed and suggesting directions for the OP to explore for improving the question.  However, it turned into an answer, so I posted it.